Mirroring shape key for blink gone wrong
I've been trying to duplicate and mirror a blink shape key so that both eyes have the same animation, it is for ARKit fave tracking, and i've watched a bunch of tutorials for simetrical and non simetrical objects, I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEjPN_QcwxU creating a Sahpe from Mix > Mirror topology and something weird happens with the vertex that breaks the shape key
This is the inside of the face in the normal blink that works:

And this is the mirrored one:


The blink transfers fine, but for some reason there is like a duplicate of the entire face that is doing a horizontal mirroring at the same time
